C++ Cli passing image pointers to WPF to display
My image processing is all in C++. Was using MFC, now exploring to upgrade to WPF. WPF side will be mainly user interface, I'm passing image pointers from unmanaged to managed for display. I found that if I'm use thread to loop the backend vector it will not display anything, but if I change it to button trigger one by one it will be functional. With the same functions, I have no idea what's going on.
WPF own my CppCli object, which it can directly call any function in c++ / cli. What could be wrong here.
wpf cs code:
private CppCli cli;

public MainWindow() { 
    cli = new CppCli(); 
    cli.ImageUpdated += Cli_ImageUpdated; // delegate and event to call method Cli_ImageUpdated 
    InitializeComponent(); 
}

private void Cli_ImageUpdated(object sender, ImageUpdateEventArgs e) 
{ 
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        MyImageControl.Source = e.img;
    });
} 

private void LiveToggle_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

    cli.LiveToggle(); 
}

Cpp cli code:
public ref class ImageUpdateEventArgs : EventArgs { 
    public: BitmapSource^ img;

    ImageUpdateEventArgs(BitmapSource^ bitmap) { 
        img = bitmap;
    } 
};

void CppCli::LiveToggle() { 
    running = !running; 

    if (running) { 
        liveThread = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(this, &MathFunctions::UpdateDisplay)); 
        liveThread->IsBackground = true; 
        liveThread->Start();
    }

    //UpdateDisplay() // This works if replace the whole thing above. 
}

void CppCli::UpdateDisplay() { 
    while (running) { // Remove this while loop and it works.

        int stride, rows, cols, bufferSize; 
        stride = cvObj->images[imageIndex].step[0]; 
        rows = cvObj->images[imageIndex].rows; 
        cols = cvObj->images[imageIndex].cols; 
        bufferSize = cvObj->images[imageIndex].total() * cvObj->images[imageIndex].elemSize(); 
        IntPtr ptr(cvObj->images[imageIndex].ptr()); 

        ImageUpdated(this, gcnew ImageUpdateEventArgs(BitmapSource::Create(cols, rows, 96, 96, PixelFormats::Bgra32, nullptr, ptr, bufferSize, stride)));

        Thread::Sleep(100); 
        imageIndex++; 
        if (imageIndex >= cvObj->images.size())
        { 
            imageIndex = 0;
        }
    } 
}


You may want to use WritaableBitmap instead of creating new BitmapSources on each ImageUpdated call. A WritableBitmap's BackBuffer can be locked to be accessible from a thread other than the UI thread.

My bad, didn't aware stackoverflow format until not readable.
I'm also testing with WriteableBitmap. Is there a way to point to different pointers with it? Means I just swap pointers for image buffers.

You would copy into the BackBuffer.

liveThread is new thread to call UpdateDisplay(). This is not main thread right?

Since the BitmapSource is created in a thread other than the UI thread, it must be frozen before being assigned to the Source property of the Image element in the UI thread:
private void Cli_ImageUpdated(object sender, ImageUpdateEventArgs e) 
{ 
    e.img.Freeze(); // call here or in the ImageUpdateEventArgs constructor

    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => MyImageControl.Source = e.img);
}

For details, please see the Remarks section in Freezable.Freeze and  Freezable.IsFrozen.

It's indeed resolved. I have some questions though: because I made a new copy of BitmapSource and it's from another background thread calling dispatch... why do we need to freeze it so it's thread safe?
I removed the sleep and noticed the frame rates aren't high. Haven't successfully done with the WriteableBitmap though.

Yes, freezing makes it cross-thread accessible. Please read the linked documentation.

the irony is that the remark never intend share the usage / purpose: "To avoid the possibility of an InvalidOperationException when calling this method, check the CanFreeze property to determine whether the Freezable can be made unmodifiable before calling this method."

By the way, you should have got an InvalidOperationException while assigning the Source property.

Interest part is: didn't seen that at all.
